# find out latest date among n date columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a function which gives the Latest date independent of number of dates passed into the function in `SQL server`

Ex.

```
Greatest(date1,date2,date3,date4,date5)
Greatest(date1,date2,date3)
```

Comment: Can you paste some code you have tried?

Comment: `select max(date_cl)
from (
 select date_0 date_cl union all
 select date_1 union all
 ....
 select date_n
) x`

Comment: I tried using table array. That is expecting to insert  values in the fuction. But I need to call this function from diffrent procedures with different values.

Comment: In general, this is a sign of a broken data model. If you have values of the same "type", such that you want to compare those values, run aggregates, etc, then all of those values should be stored (across multiple rows) in the *same* column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Table valued constructor`

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Max(dates)
        FROM   (VALUES (date1),
                       (date2)) tc(dates)) as Max_date
FROM   (SELECT '2015-01-01' AS date1,
               '2016-01-01' AS date2) a
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution with samples:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (GETDATE(), GETDATE()+1, GETDATE()-2),
    (GETDATE()-3, GETDATE()+1, GETDATE()+4)
    )T(Date1, Date2, Date3)
)
SELECT *
FROM Src
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(D) FROM (VALUES (Date1), (Date2), (Date3)) T(D)) T(MaxDate)
```

Treat `CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(D) FROM (VALUES (A), (B), ..., (Z)) T(D))` as `Greatest(A, B, ... Z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with params as you need.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Greatest
(
    @Param1 DATETIME,
    @Param2 DATETIME,
    @Param3 DATETIME,
    @Param4 DATETIME,
    @Param5 DATETIME,
    @Param6 DATETIME,
    @Param7 DATETIME,
    @Param8 DATETIME,
    @Param9 DATETIME    
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME

    SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(dates) 
    FROM
    (
        VALUES (@Param1),
            (@Param2),
            (@Param3),
            (@Param4),
            (@Param5),
            (@Param6),
            (@Param7),
            (@Param8),
            (@Param9)
    ) t(dates)

    RETURN @MaxDate

END
GO
```

Use of.

```
SELECT dbo.Greatest('2016.01.01', '2015.01.02', DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT) -- 2016-01-01 
SELECT dbo.Greatest('2016.01.01', '2015.01.02', '2016.08.20', '2014.07.06', '2013.08.01','2012.01.01',DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT) -- 2016-08-20
```